# $V(0)$ as a representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb C)$.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

For each $n\in\Bbb Z_{0}$ we have a finite dimensional, irreducible representation $V(n)$ of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb C)$ with basis $\{v_0,\cdots,v_n\}$.

For each $v_i$ we have $h(v_i) = (2i-n)v_i$.

Does this mean that $V(0)$ is just $\Bbb C$ with basis $\{v_0\}$ and this is annihilated by all of $\{e,f,h\}$? I.e. this has a single weight space $\mathfrak{g}_{i}=\{x\in V: h(x)=ix\}$, being $\mathfrak{g}_0$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @KennyWong I changed your edit, as it introduced the incorrect action of the Cartan for the general case (it just happened to coincide with the correct one for $n=0$).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yeah, you're right - thanks for fixing this!

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Isn't the new action by $h$ the one we would have if we generated the basis by lowering operators from the highest weight? Whereas my original version was just for raising from lowest weight? I.e. mine was also valid? I didn't get to see Jose's now deleted comment.

Comment: Your original was wrong in a different way. It was missing the vector itself, so it claimed to send $v_i$ to a number, rather than to that multiple of $v_i$. Otherwise yes, the difference between acting as multiplication by $n-2i$ or $-n+2i$ is just a matter of relabelling the basis (I had missed that you had the other one originally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ye$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$